# Vue.js naming conventions: 'children' of single-instance components

Tags: vue.js, naming-conventions, naming, conventions

I have been trying to adhere to the coding standards proposed in the [Vue Style Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/), but I'm not sure how to tackle this particular situation. As per the guide:

1. Components that should only ever have a single active instance should begin with the `The` prefix, to denote that there can be only one ([link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Single-instance-component-names-strongly-recommended)).
2. Child components that are tightly coupled with their parent should include the parent component name as a prefix ([link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Tightly-coupled-component-names-strongly-recommended)).

How should these combine? Imagine a typical web page with a single-instance header. Inside it we would have a number of header links, specific to the header (they wouldn't appear elsewhere).

If I follow (1), my header component becomes `TheHeader`, but if I were to also follow (2) I would have to name my header links `TheHeaderLink`. This is misleading, since there will typically be more than one. If I drop the `The` for links, I lose the benefit of having coupled components listed together alphabetically.

Conversely, if I drop the `The` for the header and go with `AppHeader` and `AppHeaderLink`, I'm no longer conveying the fact that the header is a singleton.

I guess this boils down to personal preference and/or coding team standards, but maybe there's some convention or solution I'm failing to see?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that Node.js allows you to `require` or `import` [folders as modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules), I personally like to "enclose" or organize child components (tightly coupled with their parent) in a self-contained folder, and provide a single entry point to it.

So, I would go from this...

```
components/
|- TheHeader.vue
|- TheHeaderLink.vue
|- TheHeaderLogo.vue
```

...to that:

```
components/
|- TheHeader/
   |- index.vue
   |- HeaderLink.vue
   |- HeaderLogo.vue
```

With the `index.vue` being the (aforementioned) entry point, which is basically your original `TheHeader` component renamed.

And of course you would import it as usual:

```js
import TheHeader from '@/components/TheHeader';
// or
const TheHeader = require('@/components/TheHeader');
```

But yeah, I think it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: Oh, neat. I started my project with a similar folder structure, and was in the process of refactoring after reading the style guide. Specifically, it says it's better to avoid folders (https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Tightly-coupled-component-names-strongly-recommended, inside Detailed Explanation), but I guess it's a matter of weighing pros and cons.

Comment: Ahh, so it's even there in the docs (the detailed explanation shouldn't really be in hidden section though). But well, I believe this self-contained folder thing makes more sense in our case, as organizing libraries and stuff in one is a lot easier. I usually keep it to a maximum of 1 to 2 nested folder(s) to keep it organized, and won't have to worry that much about the rapid file switching.